# Сравнение строк из массива (textbox1) с строками из MySQL C#

Tags: c#, desktop

Нужно сравнить строки, которые записаны в textBox1 и строки из базы данных.
В массив `string[] s;` я записываю все строки из textBox1. Затем в цикле while пытаюсь сравнить их с теми, что приходят из базы, если строки совпадают, то нужно увеличить переменную `minusWords` на +1, если не совпадают, то увеличивается переменная `plusWords` на +1.

Так-же некорректно считаются минус и плюс слова, все в одну кучу лепит, возможно дело в самом цикле, честно, в данный момент ответить не смогу на этот вопрос.

Таким образом данный алгоритм должен убирать строки из textBox1, которые уже есть в базе данных и оставлять только те, которых нет. Долблюсь лбом об монитор битый час, прошу помощи, коллеги.

Вот мой код

```
            //-------------запуск таймера------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
            Stopwatch sw_total = new Stopwatch();
            sw_total.Start();
            try
            {
                string connStr =
                       "server=localhost;" +
                       "user=root;" +
                       "database=test;" +
                       "password=;";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT `numbers` FROM numbers";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // ---------------------- Считываем строки из textbox1 -----------------------------------
                String[] s = textBox1.Text.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                String[] temp;
                if (!reader.HasRows)
                    MessageBox.Show("Таблица пуста");
                else
                {
                    int nRows = 0;
                    int minusWords = 0;
                    int plusWords = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        object number = reader["numbers"];
                        if (number.Equals(s[nRows]))
                        {
                            ++minusWords;
                        }
                        else
                            ++plusWords;
                    }
                    lblMinusWords.Text = $"Минус-слова: {minusWords}";
                    lblPlusWords.Text = $"Плюс-слова: {plusWords}";
                    
                    MessageBox.Show("end");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
            }
            //-------------вывод результата таймера----------------------------------------------------------------------//
            sw_total.Stop();
            lblTime.Text = ("Reading: " + sw_total.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
```

Comment: Код не читал, но алгоритм может быть такой: 1) считать все строки из бд и записать в `HashSet<String>` 2) для каждой строки в текстбоксе проверить есть ли она в хешсете из бд

Comment: Код прочитал, ошибка понятна (вы сделали цикл по словам из базы, но не сделали цикл по своему массиву слов), но лучше реализуйте алгоритм @tym32167 - это более скоростной алгоритм.

Comment: @AK попробовал способ tym32167, в описании добавил проблему, как здесь быть?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, помогло, появилась еще одна проблема, в описании дополнил, буду благодарен за помощь в решении

Comment: @AK понял, тем не менее, как решить этот нюанс?

Comment: @AK оператор прерывания здесь не помог, я пробовал делать ```return```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сделали цикл по словам из базы, но не сделали цикл по своему массиву слов из текстбокса.

Вот так это должно выглядеть примерно:

```
var stringsFromDb = new string[] { "мама", "мыла", "раму" };
var stringsFromTxtBox = new string[] { "мама", "но", "раму", "же", "есть", "надо!" };

int minusWords = 0;
int plusWords = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < stringsFromTxtBox.Length; i++)
{
    bool wordFound = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < stringsFromDb.Length; j++)
    {
        if(string.Equals(stringsFromTxtBox[i], stringsFromDb[j], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            wordFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(wordFound)
    {
        plusWords++;
    }
    else
    {
        minusWords++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(minusWords);
Console.WriteLine(plusWords);
```

Иначе вы сравниваете слово из базы с первым словом из текстбокса, либо (если наивно добавите инкремент для nRows) будете сравнивать i'тое слово из базы с i'тым словом из текстбокса, что разумеется даст неверный ответ.

Решение -- вложенный цикл, это *самый* медленный вариант, его сложность O(N^2) и вам нужно научиться такие решения делать, а потом когда начнёт получаться -- перейти к изучению более быстрых алгоритмов. Пример такого алгоритма вам дали в первом комментарии к вопросу.

PS Вы можете скачать сразу все строки из базы в переменную. Это очень удобно, если у вас алгоритм будет состоять из трёх шагов: А) ввод данных б) расчёт в) вывод. Вы сможете разбить код на отдельные методы, каждый из которых в соответствии с принципом единой ответственности будет делать что-то одно. Такой код читать и понимать будет гораздо проще. А также вы сможете потренироваться в написании циклов используя два массива строк - на том примере, который привёл я, а потом уже переходить к своему реальному примеру.