# Запись минус и плюс строк в переменную C# textbox и MySQL

Tags: c#, desktop

В продолжение моего вопроса [Сравнение строк из массива (textbox1) с строками из MySQL C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1224010/213987)

Пытаюсь сравнить строки из базы данных и дальше разделить на "минус-слова" и "плюс-слова". Минус-слова — это слова, которые уже существуют в базе данных (проверяется путем сравнения строки из textbox1 и строк из базы данных), "плюс-слова" — строки, которых нет в базе данных (они должны сохраняться в новую коллекцию таких "плюс-слов" и выводить в `label` общее кол-во плюс-слов, которые существуют в этой коллекции.

В моем случае почему-то попадает строка из "минус-слов" в коллекцию "плюс-слов", я пробовал использовать оператор прерывания `return`, но это явно не то.

Пример на скриншотах ниже
База данных с тестовыми номерами (которые и проверяются в программе на схожесть) 
[image: База данных с номерами для теста]

Результат работы программы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //-------------запуск таймера------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
            Stopwatch sw_total = new Stopwatch();
            sw_total.Start();
            try
            {
                string connStr =
                       "server=localhost;" +
                       "user=root;" +
                       "database=test;" +
                       "password=;";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT `numbers` FROM numbers";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int nRows = 0;              // number of rows in mysql database
                int minusWords = 0;
                // ---------------------- Считываем строки из textbox1 -----------------------------------
                String[] s = textBox1.Text.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                HashSet<string> str = new HashSet<string>();
                HashSet<string> RowsString = new HashSet<string>();
                HashSet<string> MinusString = new HashSet<string>();
                HashSet<string> PlusString = new HashSet<string>();
                for (int k = 0; k < s.Length; ++k)
                {
                    str.Add(s[k]);
                }
                if (!reader.HasRows)
                    MessageBox.Show("Таблица пуста");
                else
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string number = reader["numbers"].ToString();
                        RowsString.Add(number);
                        nRows++;
                    }
                    foreach (string _str in str)
                    {
                        foreach(string _rows in RowsString)
                        {
                            if (_str.Contains(_rows) == true)
                            {
                                minusWords++;
                                MessageBox.Show("OK");
                                lblMinusWords.Text = $"Минус-слов: {minusWords}";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (_str.Contains(_rows) != true)
                                    PlusString.Add(_str);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show($"All rows == {nRows}");
                    MessageBox.Show("Last in MySQL: " + RowsString.Last()
                    .Trim()
                    .ToString());
                    reader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                // ---------------------------------- плюс строки -------------------------------------
                int pCount = 0;
                foreach (var count in PlusString)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(count);
                    pCount++;
                }
                lblPlusWords.Text = $"Плюс-слов: {pCount}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            //-------------вывод результата таймера----------------------------------------------------------------------//
            sw_total.Stop();
            lblTime.Text = ("Reading: " + sw_total.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сравнению с предыдущим вопросом алгоритм даже упрощается, главное вам надо понять почему и как использование HashSet упрощает поиск в нём слова и позвоняет снизить сложность алгоритма с O(N^2) до O(N).

```
var stringsFromDb = new string[] { "мама", "мыла", "раму" };
var stringsFromTxtBox = new string[] { "мама", "но", "раму", "же", "есть", "надо!" };
var set = new HashSet<string>(stringsFromDb);

int minusWords = 0;
int plusWords = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < stringsFromTxtBox.Length; i++)
{
    if (set.Contains(stringsFromTxtBox[i]))
    {
        plusWords++;
        Console.WriteLine($"слово '{stringsFromTxtBox[i]}' содержится в базе");
        // TODO занести в HashSet<string> PlusString
    }
    else
    {
        minusWords++;
        Console.WriteLine($"слово '{stringsFromTxtBox[i]}' НЕ содержится в базе");
        // TODO занести в HashSet<string> MinusString
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(minusWords);
Console.WriteLine(plusWords);
```

А в остальном решение выдаёт тот же самый ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень, очень, очень благодарен)

Comment: @byte_ Первое. Вам лучше знать свои данные, но не факт, что минусслова и плюсслова нужно загонять в `HashSet`, а не в `List` (то есть иначе вы уверены, что на входе вам не/встретятся повторы слов). Второе. У меня есть строчка `var set = new HashSet<string>(stringsFromDb);` и вы по-прежнему недооцениваете, насколько вам самому проще будет читать свой код, насколько он станет нагляднее, если вы отделите операцию чтения из базы в отдельный метод, а расчёт в другой. Затрат на копейку, но текущий ваш код описывается термином "лапшекод" (спагетти на en so) и потому вам так трудно разобраться в нём.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не указали, имеет ли столбец с номерами-строками ограничение на уникальность.

**Решение**

Предполагается уникальность столбца с номерами-строками. try-catch и прочие проверки не использовал, т.к. это пример.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = "...";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();

        List<string> userNumbers = textBox1.Text
            .Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToList();

        string sql = "SELECT number FROM numbers";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int minusCount = 0; // Которые есть в БД.
        int plusCount = userNumbers.Count; // Которых нет в БД.
        int totalCount = 0; // Всего в БД.

        string dbNumber;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            totalCount++;
            dbNumber = reader["number"].ToString();

            if (userNumbers.Any(n => n == dbNumber))
            {
                userNumbers.Remove(dbNumber);
                minusCount++;
                plusCount--;
            }
        }

        label1.Text = $"Всего строк в БД: {totalCount}";
        label2.Text = $"Минус-строк: {minusCount}";
        label3.Text = $"Плюс-строк: {plusCount}";
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это хорошее напоминание про не/уникальность, тоже оставлял подобный комментарий, но лишь в качестве иллюстрации и мелкой ремарки, а не сконцентировался на этом моменте. Но вот что мне [кажется избыточным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1221879/213987) - так это button1_Click: отдельно метод загрузки из базы, отдельно расчёт, отдельно клик. Это же один из базовых принципов проектирования (SRP из SOLID), код читать проще, нагляднее, проще тестировать. А так вот захочет кто-то протестировать метод нажатия кнопки - а он и расчёты делает и в базу ходит...

Comment: Я исправил метод автора button1_Click(), о большем не просили. Вы правы насчет разграничения ответственности в архитектуре ПО, но для больших проектов, а не для Hello-World-приложений, которые только раздуются.

Comment: Согласен, о большем не просили -- это железный аргумент, так что воспринимайте это не как критику вашего ответа, а продолжение дискуссии с топикстартером. В моей практике просто постоянно мелкие проекты со временем развиваются и превращаются в крупные, поэтому приходится думать о архитектуре с самого начала.